# Invalid hook call when starting to use Material UI

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have been working on an app for a while and want to change from Chakra UI to Material UI. But as soon as I try to use any object from the Material UI library such as, `<Grid></Grid>` or `<Box></Box>`
I get the error message

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

I suspect this is beacous of some dependecy some how chakra and matrial getting two reacts into the prodject?

I have read some other stack overflows on how to solve the problem and have removed the `node_modules` and re-installed it. But nothing have worked so far.

If possible I would like to keep the old elements I have created with Chakra UI and just start using Material UI on the new ones.

This is my dependency's.

```
+-- @chakra-ui/icons@2.0.17
| +-- @chakra-ui/icon@3.0.16        
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped        
| +-- @chakra-ui/system@2.5.5       
| | +-- @chakra-ui/color-mode@2.1.12
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-utils@2.0.12
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @chakra-ui/react@2.5.5
| +-- @chakra-ui/accordion@2.1.11
| | +-- @chakra-ui/descendant@3.0.14
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-context@2.0.8
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-controllable-state@2.0.8
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-merge-refs@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/alert@2.1.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/avatar@2.2.8
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-children-utils@2.0.6
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/breadcrumb@2.1.5
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/button@2.0.18
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/card@2.1.6
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/checkbox@2.2.14
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-types@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-callback-ref@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-safe-layout-effect@2.0.5
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-update-effect@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/close-button@2.0.17
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/control-box@2.0.13
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/counter@2.0.14
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/css-reset@2.1.1
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/editable@2.0.21
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-focus-on-pointer-down@2.0.6
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/focus-lock@2.0.16
| | +-- react-focus-lock@2.9.4
| | | +-- react-clientside-effect@1.2.6
| | | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | | +-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | | +-- use-callback-ref@1.3.0
| | | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | | `-- use-sidecar@1.1.2
| | |   `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/form-control@2.0.18
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/hooks@2.1.6
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/image@2.0.15
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/input@2.0.21
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/layout@2.1.18
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/live-region@2.0.13
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/media-query@3.2.12
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/menu@2.1.12
| | +-- @chakra-ui/clickable@2.0.14
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-animation-state@2.0.8
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-disclosure@2.0.8
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-focus-effect@2.0.9
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-outside-click@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/modal@2.2.11
| | +-- react-remove-scroll@2.5.5
| | | +-- react-remove-scroll-bar@2.3.4
| | | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | | +-- react-style-singleton@2.2.1
| | | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/number-input@2.0.19
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-event-listener@2.0.7
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-interval@2.0.5
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/pin-input@2.0.20
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/popover@2.1.9
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/popper@3.0.13
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/portal@2.0.16
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/progress@2.1.6
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/provider@2.2.2
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/radio@2.0.22
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/react-env@3.0.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/select@2.0.19
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/skeleton@2.0.24
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-previous@2.0.5
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/slider@2.0.23
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-latest-ref@2.0.5
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-pan-event@2.0.9
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-size@2.0.10
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/spinner@2.0.13
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/stat@2.0.18
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/switch@2.0.26
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/table@2.0.17
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/tabs@2.1.9
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/tag@3.0.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/textarea@2.0.19
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/toast@6.1.1
| | +-- @chakra-ui/react-use-timeout@2.0.5
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/tooltip@2.2.7
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/transition@2.0.16
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @chakra-ui/visually-hidden@2.0.15
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @emotion/react@11.10.6
| +-- @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @emotion/styled@11.10.6
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.2.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @mui/icons-material@5.11.11
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- framer-motion@10.11.2
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-circular-progressbar@2.1.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-dom@18.2.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-router-dom@6.9.0
| +-- react-router@6.9.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
`-- react@18.2.0
```

The following gives me error if it is "Box" and not if it is "Flex"

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import {Flex} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as React from "react";


export default function Test() {

  return (<Box>
      </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't reproduce this: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cherry-8uw0q1?file=/src/App.tsx